1-Bromo-4-tert-butylbenzene reaction with NaNH2

I'm struggling to grasp how the reaction would turn out. Could you help?
My idea was that the bromide atom will get replaced by the amino group of $\ce{NaNH2}$, but when I google, I read that $\ce{NaNH2}$ is a strong base and so there might also be other possibilities like a deprotonation.
Disclaimer: also asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/chemhelp/comments/1bxea94/1bromo4tertbutylbenzene_reaction_with_nanh2/

Deprotonation to give benzyne seems most likely

A mixture of products seems even more likely.

I’m voting to close this question because we discourage cross-posting within the network and outside it.

The reaction will proceed by deprotonation of the benzene ring to give the benzyne, an unstable intermediate, which then will react with ammonia/amide anion to give a mixture of m and p t-butyl aniline.

How would $ortho$ product ever form?

By the addition of iso-butylene to aniline   https://patents.google.com/patent/US4892974A/en

Sorry, I'm not following.  The aryne intermediate can only produce products by addition to either end of the "triple" bond.  This would yield products with the substituent oriented either $meta$ or $para$ to the $t$-butyl group, no $ortho$ product would be formed.  Further, there is no isobutylene or silica catalyst, as claimed in your referenced patent, present in this reaction.

Sorry, my misunderstanding I thought you were asking how the o product is made. Have edited the answer
